# c# use combobox value in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, combobox, entity-framework-4

I am using the following code to generate combobox column in a datagridview using LINQ and entity framework.

```
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = null;
var context = new BatchEntities(); 
var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Take(0);
var source = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };

dgvLoadTable.DataSource = source;
dgvLoadTable.ReadOnly = false;
dgvLoadTable.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

var practices = (from p in context.TABLE1 select p.PRACTICE).Distinct();

for(int r= 0; r < dgvLoadTable.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < dgvLoadTable.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        if(c == 2 || c == 4)
        {
            this.dgvLoadTable[c, r] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            foreach(var name in practices)
                ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvLoadTable[c, r]).Items
                                                              .AddRange(practices.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

Here, in the for loop, I am setting the items of combobox using var practices, but for different columns the items will be different. In this way, I have to create different variable for each column. Is there a way to do this using a general code, where tablename will be selected from cboSelectTable and the column will be selected by its index as stated in the if statement. Help if possible, thanks.

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, WPF or something else?

Comment: Why are you doing a `foreach` on the `practices` just to do an `AddRange(practices)`?  Seems like that should be just the `AddRange` without the `foreach` or a `foreach` where you `Add(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert a Checkboxrow with the following code:

**CODE**

> ```
>             DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
>             dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
>             chk.HeaderText = "Check Data";
>             chk.Name = "chk";
>             dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = true;
> ```

Normally you call the cells with the "CurrentCell" methode... e.g:

**CODE**

```
private void dgvLoadTable_CelldoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       //do some code here
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // Check the current ColumnIndex...
        {
            //do some code here

        }
```

so you mustn´t set a variable for each row. I hope this help you!